# How to split strings within a list?

Tags: python

so i did:

```
indexlist = list(zip(indexcsv['2006'], indexcsv['2006col']))
```

I get a list like this

```
[('2', 1),
 ('5+12', 2),
 ('6', 2),
 ('7+5', 2),
 ('8', 2),
 ('9', 2)]
```

1) i want to split those elements with the + character, eg `('7+5',2)` into `(('7','5'),2)`.

I tried:

```
for i in indexlist:
    i.split("+")
```

but that gave me an error about tuples have no attribute split..what am i doing wrong. If I can't even split an element within a list, what else can pandas do?

2) if #1 gets solved, if i have to add up all the x values (x,y) or ((x1,x2),y) in this list  (in this case 2 + 5 + 12 + 6 + 7 + 5 + 8 + 9) .how go i iterate through the list to do the addition since some of these will be a list within the list (eg (7,5)), so I can't just do .sum()

this language is so difficult

Comment: Can you at least show your efforts?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with pandas either. And no, the fact that you create the list from some columns does not count.

Comment: what else do i need to show?

Comment: it has to do with pandas because i used read_csv , which is supposed to load the columns into a dataframe...after like an hour of research...i figured out how to zip two columns from the dataframe into a list , so i can start working on it

Comment: then i will be using this list of indices (colums, index/rows) to extract the corresponding data from another dataframe

Comment: See my second comment above.

Comment: Based on the way you've written the question and the responses you've given, I can only surmise that you're just starting out in Python. I have to suggest a good, thorough Python tutorial. The problem you're having can be solved easily with a solid understanding of the basics of Python data structures.

Comment: saw it, thought it's not very helpful and not pointing me the right direction in solving this problem...seems like you're high

Comment: Silvio Mayolo...obviously, i'm a beginner...but the issue is, Python seems to lack any good resource online...with any other language, those resources would've been easily found

Comment: why did you build the tuples in the first place, if you don't need them?

Comment: Python has an official tutorial on their website, which I highly recommend. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: i build those tuples becase they store the indicies (row, column index) of the data I need to extract from another dataframe..am i supposed to be using a non-tuple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to split the tuple than the element of tuple.

```
for i in indexlist:
   j = i[0].split("+")
```

To do the summing as well,

```
sum_ = 0
for i in indexlist:       
   j = [int(x) for x in i[0].split("+")]        
   sum_ += sum(j)
```

Comment: thanks ...i'll give that a try... need a regular pandas/python mentor....it's more complicated than C#/VB to me to me... ...if anyone wants to be a mentor.. ,i will pay..

Comment: What is the rate? :P

Comment: Meh. Just tag me if you want. I'd be happy to help for free :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to step through your list, which contains tuples, then convert the first element to an integer, then sum them up.

The trick is what to do when there is a `+` sign and deal with that condition:

```
total = 0
for item in your_list:
   x, y = item
   if '+' in x:
     a, b = x.split('+')
     total += int(a) + int(b)
   else:
     total += int(x)
print(total)
```

You can play with this snippet [at this repl.it link](https://repl.it/repls/KindQuizzicalMultiprocessing).